# How to know if you are not over-filtered in matlab?

Tags: matlab, filter, signals, noise-reduction

For example, I have a signal like this

[image: the link of the figure...]

I don't want the higher frequency sin wave(the noise). I know I can filter it by using a FIR filter. But I can't tell if it's over-filtered. As below, the signal is like the first graph, how can I know if the real signal is like the second or the bottom graph?

Comment: If you look at the plots the magnitudes are the same. It's just looks slightly different due to the scale.

Comment: I don't think you can, in general. How do you define what you mean by "real"?

Comment: Yes I know the magnitudes are the same. This is only an example, it‘s not the real case.

Comment: By "real" I mean the signal without noise or nearly without noise. So generally I can't know if the signal is close enough to the real signal, right?